# How is the Keras Conv1D input specified? I seem to be lacking a dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv1d

My input is a array of 64 integers.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add( Input(shape=(68,), name="input"))
model.add(Conv1D(64, 2, activation="relu", padding="same", name="convLayer"))
```

I have 10,000 of these arrays in my training set.  And I supposed to be specifying this in order for conv1D to work?

I am getting the dreaded

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer convLayer is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 68]
```

error and I really don't understand what I need to do.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't let the name confuse you. The layer `tf.keras.layers.Conv1D` needs the following shape: `(time_steps, features)`. If your dataset is made of `10,000` samples with each sample having `64` values, then your data has the shape `(10000, 64)`, which is not directly applicable to the `tf.keras.layers.Conv1D` layer. You are missing the `time_steps` dimension. What you can do is use the `tf.keras.layers.RepeatVector`, which repeats your array input `n` times, in the example `5`. This way your `Conv1D` layer gets an input of the shape `(5, 64)`. Check out the documentation for more [information](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/RepeatVector):

```py
time_steps = 5
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(64,), name="input"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.RepeatVector(time_steps))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(64, 2, activation="relu", padding="same", name="convLayer"))
```

As a side note, you should ask yourself if using a `tf.keras.layers.Conv1D` layer is the right option for your use case. This layer is usually used for NLP and other time series tasks. For example, in sentence classification, each word in a sentence is usually mapped to a high-dimensional word vector representation, as seen in the image. This results in data with the shape `(time_steps, features)`.

[image]

If you want to use character one hot encoded embeddings it would look something like this:

[image]

This is a simple example of one single sample with the shape `(10, 10)` --> 10 characters along the time series dimension and 10 features. It  should help you understand the tutorial I mentioned a bit better.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am struggling understanding the documentation. I'm a beginner and am experimenting.  My particular project us to read a 64 character string and determine if it is an email address, URL, integer, float, word, or noise.  Conv1D is good for this, right? In my experiment, I am hoping to discover important markers such as "@", "://", ".", etc

Comment: One thing I cannot wrap my head around is why I should specify my number of training samples.  I solved the problem above already using a big ol' stack of Dense layers and it didn't care a bit about the samples.  Is the kernel moving down a single data vector (a single email address) or is it moving down the first character of each sample?

Comment: To your first question: Yes, it is definitely possible if you split each email address into characters (time series dimension) and use for example one hot encoding embedding (feature dimension). Please refer to this [tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/character-level-cnn-with-keras-50391c3adf33)

Comment: To your second question: where exactly are you specifying the number of your training samples?

Comment: Ok, I malfunctioned. Previous thing I tried seemed to want that info; not now.  I misunderstood the "repeatVector" thing, evidently thinking that this was for the data set size I had previously specified.  Only now do I see the 64, lol.  I'll have to read up on that.

Comment: Thank you, my "syntax" errors are corrected, now I can begin understanding what this is doing.

Answer (score 0):

The Conv1D layer does temporal convolution, that is, along the first dimension (not the batch dimension of course), so you should put something like this:

```
time_steps = 5
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(time_steps, 64), name="input"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(64, 2, activation="relu", padding="same", name="convLayer"))
```

You will need to slice your data into time_steps temporal slices to feed the network.

However, if your arrays don't have a temporal structure, then conv1D is not the layer you are looking for.