# What is the proper way to implement a dropout layer in a CNN?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dropout

Is this proceeding correct?

My intention was to add a dropout layer after concatenation, but to do so i needed to adjust the concat layer's output to the appropriate [shape](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/SpatialDropout1D) **(samples, timesteps, channels)**, hence expanding the dimension from `(None, 4096) to (None, 1, 4096)` and consequently undo the operation after the output.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to use the `SpatialDropout1D` layer, it has to receive a 3D tensor `(batch_size, time_steps, features)`, so adding an additional dimension to your tensor before feeding it to the dropout layer is one option that is perfectly legitimate.
Note, though, that in your case you could use both `SpatialDropout1D` or `Dropout`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

samples = 2
timesteps = 1
features = 5
x = tf.random.normal((samples, timesteps, features))
s = tf.keras.layers.SpatialDropout1D(0.5)
d = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)

print(s(x, training=True))
print(d(x, training=True))
```

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[-0.5976591  1.481788   0.         0.         0.       ]]

 [[ 0.        -4.6607018 -0.         0.7036132  0.       ]]], shape=(2, 1, 5), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[[[-0.5976591  1.481788   0.5662646  2.8400114  0.9111476]]

 [[ 0.        -0.        -0.         0.7036132  0.       ]]], shape=(2, 1, 5), dtype=float32)
```

I think that `SpatialDropout1D` layers are most suitable after `CNN` layers.

Comment: Thank you very much, i will do a little bit more research about the difference between them. The thing here is that i have a concatenation between a feature extraction model and a model that is being trained by considering these additional features from a pre-trained model (both resnets). In this case i don't know yet which one should be better for this application.

Comment: Besides that i have searched but without much success. Do you know whay does the arg **time_steps** means?

Comment: It is just a spatial / temporal dimension. Check this post for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69591717/how-is-the-keras-conv1d-input-specified-i-seem-to-be-lacking-a-dimension/69594400#69594400.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of explicitly adding a new dimension, in tensorflow 2.7.0 you could just use keepdims=True as an argument of the GlobalAveragePooling2D layer.

Example:

```
def TestModel():
  # specify the input shape
  in_1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape = (256,256,3))
  in_2 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape = (256,256,3))

  x1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3))(in_1)
  x1 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU()(x1)
  x1 = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(keepdims = True)(x1)

  x2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3))(in_2)
  x2 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU()(x2)
  x2 = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(keepdims = True)(x2)
 
  x = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([x1,x2])
  x = tf.keras.layers.SpatialDropout2D(0.2)(x)
  x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1000)(x)

  # create the model
  model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=(in_1,in_2), outputs=x)

  return model

#Testcode
model = TestModel()
model.summary()
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=True, expand_nested=False, show_dtype=True, to_file="model.png")
```

[image]

If you require to squeeze it in the end, you could still do it.

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem is that the output of my avg pool layer has shape (None, 2048), this way i don't see how preserving dims could help me cause i would have to expand it. Anyway thank you for the tip, i didn't knew this one.