# Conv 1d and its input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, keras-layer

I have a numpy array of array with shape (273, 168) so 273 sample and every sample has 168 observation.

I want as output 273 array of 24 observations.

Why my code give me a problem of dim differences?

```
x = np.random.randint(0,1,(273,168))
y = np.random.randint(0,1,(273,24))


model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(7, activation='relu', kernel_size=(3), input_shape=(168,273)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(24))


model.compile(loss=tf.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
            optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(),
            metrics=[tf.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()])

model.fit(x,y))

model.predcit(x[42])
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69591717/how-is-the-keras-conv1d-input-specified-i-seem-to-be-lacking-a-dimension/69594400#69594400

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the error message that you get, you can see that the required number of dimensions is 3, you are passing just 2 (n_samples, n_features), you need to reshape you data using `.reshape(n_samples, 1, n_features)` your `input_shape` is also incorrect.

Finally, you need to set `padding='same'`, or your input data runs out of dimensions. (You can try running without setting padding to same and see what error you get)

This code works:

```
x = np.random.randint(0,1,(273,168)).reshape(273, 1, 168)
y = np.random.randint(0,1,(273,24)).reshape(273, 1, 24)

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(7, activation='relu', kernel_size=(3), padding='same', input_shape=(1,168)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(24))


model.compile(loss=tf.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
            optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(),
            metrics=[tf.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()])

model.fit(x,y)
```

Comment: Ty can you give me others info about padding?

Comment: When applying convolution operation to an input (be it a vector, matrix or a tensor), the dimensions of the output get shrunk, this depends on the filter size and stride parameters. Conv layers have `padding` parameter, which can be set to `same`, which pads the output image with zeros to result in original shape. By default padding is set to `valid`, which shrinks the input.