# Input 0 of layer average_pooling1d is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 641, 191, 64)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, speech-recognition

I have input shape

```
(642, 193, 1)
```

I am passing to this layer

```
Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, input_shape=X_train.shape))

_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d (Conv1D)              (None, 642, 191, 64)      256       
=================================================================
```

and I am passing this shape to

```
AveragePooling1D(pool_size=2)
```

But I get the error

```
expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 641, 191, 64)
```

I can't figure it out. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Change your input shape to: `Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, input_shape=(193, 1))`. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69591717/how-is-the-keras-conv1d-input-specified-i-seem-to-be-lacking-a-dimension/69594400#69594400